# Strings not outputting text found using grep

Tags: grep, search

I am looking for certain strings in (Windows) executable files.

First I started with

```
grep -a string file
```

as that treats binary files like text files.
The problem there is there is no neat output, line breaks happen by chance (when the right bytes come in order) etc.pp.

So I thought I'd use strings:

```
strings file | grep -i string
```

To my astonishment 'strings' does not find strings that I was able to find using 'grep -a'. However 'strings' is nice in the way that it outputs each item of whatever it finds on a new line.

How do I get the best of both worlds? Meaning I want to really find everything and also get sensible output of what was found.

Comment: How long is the search string? `strings` by default prints printable strings with at least 4 characters, so if your search string is shorter, some lines would be missed.

Comment: Holy.... I swear I read^H^H^H^Hopened the man page. Please post as answer, will gladly accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `strings` doesn't find the same patterns as your string is most likely caused by `strings` finding patterns at least 4 characters long **and** followed by a non-printable character. From `man strings` for GNU `strings`:

```
For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character
sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given
with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.
```

In addition to that `strings` b y default only scans initialised and loaded sections of object files, which might further reduce the number of lines output.

You can try the `-a` and `-n` options to change that behaviour:

```
strings -n 1 -a file | grep -i string
```

That should get you more strings, and probably all you are expecting.

Difference in output on my `python` exececutable:

```
$ strings $(which python) | wc
  31923   68075  474068
$ strings -n 1 $(which python) | wc
 501231  531837 1541204
$ strings -n 1 -a $(which python) | wc
 501398  531995 1541762
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
grep -a string file | strings
```

---

[`strings`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strings.html) prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long. So if you `grep` for something shorter than 4 characters, processing via `strings` first will cause it to miss out. Use `strings -n 1` to set the minimum length to 1.